# Options for a file system based Sql database for a multiuser web application that can perform and scale

Tags: .net, sql, database, embedded-database

What are my options for a file based sql database (not NoSql) which scales well, performs well, and is designed for handling many hundreds of multiple users (and plays nice with .net)?

### My requirements

I'm accustomed to working with SqlServer, and for this application my needs are simpler (I still need sql though, although other parts of the application will use NoSql).

I want something which is embedded mainly because it's just simple and easy to set up, without any major overheads or services or configurations. I'd like to keep it filesystem for as long as I can.

However, when the time comes, ideally I'd like a solution which allows me to change the "context"of the database so maybe it is server based. I'd like that option to grow.

I'd also like it to be free (at least for small application, or non-commercial applications (although it will become commercial in the future...?)).

Does such a database solution exist?

### Update

Sorry guys, I used the wrong terminology and ugh ink we misunderstood each other. Forget I said embedded, I meant file base, like lucene or raven, but relational.

Comment: Small+embedded = local to a given machine, and thus **NOT** designed for multi-user approach. You can have one or the other - but not both at the same time...

Comment: I've updated my question, does that make it more clear?

Comment: Same principle applies: a **shared, file-based** system is always prone to errors, file corruption, and other messy business. If you have **multiple users** connecting - use a real server.

Comment: Thanks Marc. What about lucene and raven? I'm just asking for non nosql options and to see what's out there.

Comment: Thanks for all the 'help' guys. I think this is a good question as there is at least one answer which most of you didn't know about: Firebird. It might not be sqlservr but is still an option, surely it's useful for others to know when looking for answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FireBird, it can be embedded and scales well and deployment is really easy - an ADO.NET provider is available... see for more information http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/

Comment: Hey guys, it's good manners to leave a reason for the downvote

Answer (score 2):

You ever heard of SQL Server? Like SQL Server EMBEDDED? No install ;)

Comment: Nope never heard of sqlserver embedded.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx

Comment: +1 Cool, thanks tom-tom, I'll check it out.

Comment: The really good thing is that it scales up - you can start with it, then up ona  2008 $R2 128gb per server cluster all with the same database ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have contradictory requirements.

Small and embedded (no server) usually means SQL Server compact or SQLLite. But these are neither multi-user not network aware *in practice*.  Especially whan you say "hundreds of multiple users"

So you have to decide what you want to do. A proper, scalable, web based app with correct architecture? Or a a cheap kludgely unworkable unmaintainable mess?

SQL Server Compact will scale up of course in future to normal SQL Server with minimum fuss. But I'd start with SQL Server properly *now*

Comment: I've updated my question. Could you update the answer based on that? Thanks

Comment: I realize lucene is an search db, but it's essentially a document db, it's file based and is well suited to network apps. It's not a kludgely unworkable mess either. I'm looking for a SQL equivilante.